# Git the remote end up - strange symbols

Tags: git, ubuntu, hung

Why on my "git push" command I get the following **very scaring** error message?

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 0 | 81 KiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (1888/1888), 45.39 MiB | 4.59 MiB/s, done.
Total 1888 (delta 451), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: expected ok/error, helper said '2004�i�ʏ�&-�@0��d����UiS�5!9*�[�0�8�f
                                                                            >q+Ju�倜�6�-Y*J"�QR/���'[t����P l&���    s����C�]��b�CvNN���a����^k��
                                 S/Z�'[�cC=�aZ�0�KN�]
                                                        {�����s��}���'�[���Ϡ��*��^Ȕ�}fs�"���{�مd���>�1h����N��1���@7����@�q���?}�Y�mȽ'��x���=�](NIO^�xz��q0��7c�=���Ќӂ�˦��.!�C��k׌�r[�c�����>��3��ڧo��%�2�y�l40��}i
```

I've appended the text as it appeared on my shell, the strange symbols are shown.
Is my Git installation broken? My fist git clone was using https

I'm using `git version 1.7.4.1` on Ubuntu 10.10 x86_64

Comment: seems to be related to this issue,
http://blog.lukebennett.com/2011/07/25/git-broken-pipe-error-when-pushing-to-a-repository/